# example.com./ vs example.com/ create problems with visitor tracking programs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to search this but due to the search terms I can not find an answer anywhere.

My visitor tracking site (I use Piwik) can not decipher between the following issue below.

`example.com./` vs `example.com/`

`example.com./` when types in to find a website is of course wrong, somehow others get to my site and every page they visit shows as an external link and this `./` problem.

How can I in `.htaccess` (in my root of my domain) add a rule to fix this problem and possibly others that are similar to this?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Both methods are valid (and I don't think you can differentiate between them in .htaccess), but where are you coming across `site.com.` in real life?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is fixable from `htaccess`, as the `example.com.` hostname is invalid and any request for that will never reach your server. There's no way to rewrite outgoing requests from the browser to piwik because those requests have nothing to do with your server and thus anything htaccess wouldn't be applicable.

You need to figure out why browsers are sending tracking information to piwik with the hostname `example.com.`. Just as a wild uneducated guess, it may have to do with some inelegant appending of **hostname** and badly formed relative URI's like `<a href="./my/page.html">`. So when the code unintelligently appends them together, you get `example.com./my/page.html`.

Comment: you said " as the site.com. hostname is invalid and any request for that will never reach your server."

But people are browsing my site and the pages are pulling up this way: http://site.com./color.html and then goto http://site.com./state.html. I would think .htaccess would have a way to deal with this.

Comment: @Trance-Man htaccess has no control over the actual content that the browser gets. It can only do stuff like "instead of this page, you get this other one". You have to go through your content and remove the `.`

Comment: *as the example.com. hostname is invalid* this is completely wrong. This is a valid hostname because all domain names are in fact descendants of the root, which is `.` and since this applies to all it is not written for commodity. Any browser can go to `http://example.com./` without trouble, showing this it totally legit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTTP_HOST variable, something like the following might work.

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did not work Robert. Unless I did it wrong, anyone have ideas?

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  One thing you might be able to do w/ PWiki is to either modify the PHP input code to dynamically rewrite the host name, or depending on the DB scheme, you might be able to replace it in the DB (although this could be more problematic).

Comment: That sounds complicated, I would think there is a rewrite for apache; maybe someone here can solve?